# swift: How to call an ad made in ViewController in game scene

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have an interstitial ad declared in GameViewController and want to call it every few times my game ends. I followed a tutorial where I would call the ad by a button but I need to call from GameScene but I don't know how to call across classes. Could I use a global variable between all classes or something?
Basically I want to call func adButton() in GameScene or maybe there is some better work around.

Also, is there any way to implement reward ads or does anyone have any good tutorial like it?

Thanks very much.

```
func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {

    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: " unit id ")
    let request1 = GADRequest()
    interstitial.delegate = self
    request1.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ]
    interstitial.loadRequest(request1)
    return interstitial




}


func adButton() {

    if (self.interstitial.isReady)
    {
        self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use notifictionCenter to call the function

Add the first function in the viewDidLoad() and the second in the adButton()

In Swift 3

```
//In the gameviewcontroller
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourFunctionNameHere), name: "NSNotificationCreate" as NSNotification.Name, object: nil)
//In the gameScene use this to call the ad
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "NSNotificationCreate" as NSNotification.Name, object: nil)
```

In Swift 2

```
//In the gameviewcontroller
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "YourFunctionNameHere", name: "NSNotificationCreate", object: nil)

//In the gameScene use this to call the ad
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NSNotificationCreate", object: nil)
```

Comment: Worked absolutely perfectly thanks so much, I was stuck on this forever. Is this notification centre a way for you to send information between classes/ throughout the program? I don't need it to but could it be used for any function? Thanks again.

Comment: you can use this to call any function on another ViewController or GameScene @yellowlan

Comment: Notifications solved this issue for me. I too had been struggling to find a way to display interstitial ads for far too much time. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!